# use std::smatch as return type will cause matcher become "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "string"
#include "regex"

std::smatch match(std::string s, std::string re_s) {
    std::regex re(re_s);
    std::smatch what;
    if (std::regex_search(s, what, re)) {
        std::string s2 = what[0];
        return what;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::string s = "Ro.Unity [~/Dropbox/cs/Ro.Unity] - .../Assets/Script/Ro/UI/H.cs - JetBrains Rider";
    std::smatch m = match(s, "\\S+");
    std::string s2 = m[0];
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
    return (0);
};
```

the s2 is "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000", how to make s2 with "Ro.Unity"

in my CMakeCache.txt, the the cxx compiler is:

```
//CXX compiler
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/g++-5
```

Comment: What does your `match` return if `std::regex_search(s, what, re)` is `false`?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Older gcc versions do not handle regular expressions well....

Comment: @jan.sende I use g++-5

Comment: @asullaherc You should be fine then. By the way, what are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you write this `match` function, instead of using the regular expressions directly in the `main`?

Answer (score 4):

`std::smatch` holds iterators to the string, without making any copy of the string content. (The copy is made when the element of `std::smatch` is implicitly converted to `std::string`.) Since `match` accepts its arguments by value, the lifetime of its parameters end at the end of the function call expression, making the iterators that `std::smatch` holds become dangling iterators.

One solution is to make `match` accept `s` by reference; that is, change `std::smatch match(std::string s, std::string re_s)` to `std::smatch match(std::string& s, std::string re_s)`.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I think reference to const string is not a good idea, because it can bind to a temporary string, which we want to avoid.

Comment: I would avoid it with explicit  overload `std::smatch match(std::string const&&, std::string) = delete;` that documents such considerations better.

Comment: You saved my life. Definitely I had a dangling memory issue as my source for matching went out of scope (I was using smatch as a persistent container, but not). Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I inspire from @cpplearner answer, return std::smatch will cause this bug, but in #match code block smatch work normally, so I can get expected value in #match code block and return non-smatch type(this type include what i need value from smatch), following is my code, I can only return groups with type std::vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include "string"
#include "regex"
#include "vector"

std::vector<std::string> match(std::string s, std::string re_s) {
    std::regex re(re_s);
    std::smatch matches;
    std::vector<std::string> matches2;
    if (std::regex_search(s, matches, re)) {
        for (std::string match : matches) {
            matches2.push_back(match);
        }
    }
    return matches2;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto m = match("prpr8941", "[a-z]+(\\d+)");
    std::cout << m[1] << std::endl;
    return (0);
};
```